# Error "subscript not supported on set[Declaration]" for list comprehension in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I do not understand why I get the error I'm currently getting in Rascal.

```
|cwd:///loader.rsc|(391,1,<19,33>,<19,34>): subscript not supported on set[Declaration] at |cwd:///loader.rsc|(391,1,<19,33>,<19,34>)
Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/UnsupportedOperation/UnsupportedOperation.html|
```

I get this on the following list comprehension:

```
{asts[astIndexes[i]] | int i <- [0 .. size(astIndexes)]}
```

If needed, this is the entire file:

```
module loader

import IO;
import Set;
import List;
import lang::java::m3::Core;
import lang::java::m3::AST;
import String;

set[Declaration] asts = {};

void getAsts(list[loc] partialScanList){
    asts = {};
    for (loc m <- partialScanList)
        asts += createAstFromFile(m, true);
}

void scanMetric(void (set[Declaration]) metricFunction, list[int] astIndexes){
    metricFunction({asts[astIndexes[i]] | int i <- [0 .. size(astIndexes)]});
    println(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the subscript operator is defined on maps and relations and not on sets. For example on a `rel[int,int] x = {<1,2>}` you could `x[1]` and get `{2}`, and on `map[int,int] y = (1:2)` you could `y[1]` and get `2`.

A side-note, this codes looks like its computing lookup indexes for AST nodes, but Rascal already has pretty efficient hashes for all ADT constructor trees and those are used to lookup in relations and maps. Since these hash-codes are also integers and their distribution is pretty uniform, it is very hard to increase performance by introducing your own indexing scheme on top of this. Most likely it would degrade performance rather than improve it.

So you if you need a lookup per AST node, you could use a `rel[Declaration, Something else]`. People often also use `loc` as references to AST nodes, since they are supposed to be pretty unique. That helps if you can't keep all ASTs in memory all the time.